# *github.Issue.Repository returns NULL

Tags: rest, go, github

I am using GitHub rest api's and got familiar with the infra quite a bit. I am searching for the issues like this:

```
iIssueResults, _, ierr := client.Search.Issues(*ctx, searchQuery, searchOptions)
for _, issue := range iIssueResults.Issues {
  printVerbosef("Issue address : %p, title : %s, repo address : %p, repo URL : %s\", issue, issue.GetTitle(), issue.GetRepository(), issue.GetRepositoryURL())
}
```

where the client is my GitHub client object and ctx is my context etc with searchQuery and options. Surprisingly, I see everything coming nicely except the repo address. How is that possible that an issue does not have any repo at Git Hub. This is the output of the above snapshot.

```
Issue address : 0xc000526ea0, title : github like environment, repo address : 0x0, repo URL : https://api.github.com/repos/drdhaval2785/github_issue_backup
```

I wanted to get some more information about the repository but issue.GetRepository() is giving a null 0x0 address.

I can probably think of a hack to do this but it would not be clean. And I would want to know why is repo coming as 0x0.

Edit: There is a Go package which helps exploring git in go code. The issue class which we are speaking is [here](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-github/v40@v40.0.0/github#Issue).

Comment: What is "github rest api" to begin with? Is this some ready-made Go package/module? If yes, which one? In its current form the question is unanswerable, please work on improving it.

Comment: @kostix Edited. One should have a good picture of the question now.

Comment: Is the repository field valid in the request response? From your log, it seems like the `repository_url` is valid, but the `repository` _object_ in the response is omitted: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/issues?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-issues-assigned-to-the-authenticated-user (i.e. if you make the same request manually, either in go for via the cli, do you get a filled and valid `repository` field in the response body?)

Comment: @AlexMeuer, If you go down you would also see valid 'repository' field in the response body.

Comment: I know, I'm asking if you are _actually_ receiving a `repository` in the response body. That would be the most obvious reason for the go struct not to contain it (since the go struct uses a pointer, it is therefore nullable). By checking if we're actually receiving a repository structure, we bisect our debug search space.